# Trying to return the text value of a class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to return the text value, "My account" which is also a link.

I need to check the string to  to prove i have logged into a website or not.

I have tried all the usual methods (xpath, by css , by href) but without success.. I am clearly doing something wrong.

can someone help me out with this ?

Hopefully the html image will show what i am trying to achieve. (click on code to display)

here is the code i am using to log into a site, when i login, the text "My account" appears as a href.  I want to then return the href text to write to a spreadsheet.

See code snippet and some of the methods i have tried to return the href text string (i have tried many more .. but deleted them now as the didnt work)

Also see the result code.

```
    WebElement element_search1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']")).click();

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Login - mysite.com"));;

    WebElement element_search2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subscriber_email']"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subscriber_email']"));
    element_search2.clear();
    element_search2.sendKeys("email@email.com");
    element_search2.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

// find and enter password
WebElement element_search3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subscriber_password']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='subscriber_password']"));
element_search3.clear();
element_search3.sendKeys("password");    
driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();

 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account")).getAttribute("class"));
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account")).getText());
```

**Result**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"My account"}
```

it fails on : `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.linkText("My account")).getAttribute("class"))`

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking here... 
It would be better if we had the classes, and what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please learn how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show all the usual methods you tried and their output.

Comment: It's (still) unclear what you're asking for. Title says "how to get text value of a class" and message says "how to get the href text string"? What is it that you want? Please remove the irrelevant test code and leave the one or two lines that don't deliver the expected output and also add the expected output. Add the DOM structure in question (copied from the development tools) to the question. Please also remove the sentence referring to a link that's actually not present. You won't get the correct answer unless your question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To retrive the text value of a class "user-info" i.e. **`My account`** you can use the following lines of code:

```
String my_account = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class='main-top-nav']//a[@class='user-info' and contains(@href,'/home/manage_account')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(my_account);
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.